# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE and search values in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I use a txt file to upload data into a mysql database.
The txt file I use is the following:

```
http://www.repubblica.it/
http://www.repubblica.it/minify/sites/repubblica/nazionale/config_01.cache.php?name=site_home_css
http://www.repubblica.it/minify/sites/repubblica/nazionale/config_01.cache.php?name=social_home_css
http://quotidiano.repubblica.it/home?adv=t&source=homerepit
http://www.repubblica.it/servizi/mobile/index.html
http://inchieste.repubblica.it/
http://espresso.repubblica.it/
http://altoadige.gelocal.it/
http://corrierealpi.gelocal.it/
http://gazzettadimantova.gelocal.it/
http://gazzettadimodena.gelocal.it/
http://gazzettadireggio.gelocal.it/
http://mattinopadova.gelocal.it/
http://ilpiccolo.gelocal.it/
http://trentinocorrierealpi.gelocal.it/
http://lacittadisalerno.gelocal.it/
```

In my java program I use the following mysql code to upload the txt file:

```
//here I create the table
CREATE TABLE table(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,url VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL);"

//here the txt is loaded
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'/tmp/test/url.txt\' INTO TABLE table LINES (url)
```

All that works fine. I have my table with two columns: id and url.
[image]

When i try to search a value in that table using a simple:

```
SELECT url FROM table WHERE url LIKE 'http://www.repubblica.it/'
```

or

```
SELECT url FROM table WHERE url ='http://www.repubblica.it/'
```

MySQL return an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )
Here a screenshot of phpmyadmin:
[image: LIKE]

[image: equal]
Why I am not able to seach for my values?
What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need wildcards: `LIKE '%http://www.repubblica.it/%'`

Comment: You only need a wildcard at the end, putting one at the start will disable all use of indexes. `LIKE 'http://www.repubblica.it/%'`

Answer (score 0):

You need use wildcards in your like statment `LIKE '%..%'` to match a part of a string

```
SELECT url FROM table WHERE url LIKE '%http://www.repubblica.it/%'
```

If you try to search directly on `phpmysqmin` you have an option to search by 'LIKE %..%'

Comment: It works but using LIKE '%...%' search (example %http://www.repubblica.it/%) it returns also "wrong" values like:
1. http://www.repubblica.it/
2.http://www.repubblica.it/minify/sites/repubblica/nazionale/config_01.cache.php?name=site_home_css

and so on.
I need to know if a specific url is present.

Comment: @RickyGeek For an exact match, don't use LIKE, just `SELECT url FROM table WHERE url='http://www.repubblica.it/'`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Using the '=' operator no results are returned. That's my issue!

Comment: @RickyGeek maybe you should do a `TRIM` on url column ... or better yet when you load the data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have spaces before and after the string, try this:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `url`=TRIM(`url`)
```

Then:

```
SELECT 
  `url` 
FROM 
  `table` 
WHERE 
  `url`='http://www.repubblica.it/'
```